# how to integrate Hudson with Sonar For C#( dotnet projects)

Tags: hudson, integration, sonarqube

I am working on Hudson with Sonar without Using Maven.I successfully configured Hudson and it works but I don't know how to integrate sonar with hudson after builds I need to run the code analysis.

Any Help will appreciable!!

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advise you to install the [Sonar Hudson/Jenkins plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=116359341) that will allow you to define a Sonar Runner build step on which you will be able to either pass Sonar properties on the fly or pass the location of your "sonar-project.properties" file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are building the code via ant, I would follow this guide: [Installing and Configuring Sonar Ant Task](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+Sonar+Ant+Task) which will execute sonar and use the sonar plugin to deploy to the sonar server. The [tutorial](http://www.sonarsource.org/a-new-hudson-plugin-for-a-closer-integration-with-sonar/) that's provided by the sonar team suggests that you create a small pom.xml file to just execute the sonar targets.